# MySql > select record only form yesterday

Tags: mysql

I want to select all record form yesterday

I use the following

```
date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1
```

but this select today records as will

I just want to select yesterdays records

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong. It should be the following:

```
date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND date < CURDATE()
```

`CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY -> date of yesterday.`

In order to select records of yesterday only you can use the condition given above or the condition given below:

```
date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: thanks, and what if I want to select 2 days before 
I mean not today and not yesterday but the day before only ?

Comment: then you can use either `date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY` **or** `date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`